# It is posible to add string with byte?

Tags: c#

How to append string and byte array?

```
String array="$MT!BOOTLOADER";  
Byte[] hexdecimal={0x01,0x05,0x0036};
```

Comment: Do you really mean `0x0036`?

Comment: Pretty sure no overload exists for the + operator between byte[] and string, did you want to add the bytes to the written string or the strings bytes to the byte array?

Comment: What methods have you tried?

Comment: @leppie Is there anything special about `0x0036`?

Comment: @Nolonar: It depends if you just want to byte value of `0x36` or actually both bytes.

Comment: @leppie: 0x0036 is the command code for socket alive

Comment: @user2720620: But `0x0036` is not a `byte`, it is a `short` (or 2 bytes if you will).

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do something low level, so in the end you won't need a `string` but a `byte[]`, so:

```
string array="$MT!BOOTLOADER";  
byte[] hexdecimal={0x01,0x05,0x36};
byte[] bytesOrig = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(array);
byte[] bytesFinal = bytesOrig;
Array.Resize(ref bytesFinal, bytesFinal.Length + hexdecimal.Length);
Array.Copy(hexdecimal, 0, bytesFinal, bytesOrig.Length, hexdecimal.Length);

// bytesFinal contains all the bytes
```

I'm using `Encoding.ASCII` because your signature is ASCII (and normally signatures *are* ASCII)

equivalent code, but little different (we preallocate the array with the right size, by doing two calls to `Encoding.ASCII` methods)

```
string array="$MT!BOOTLOADER";  
byte[] hexdecimal={0x01,0x05,0x36};
int count = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(array);
byte[] bytes = new byte[count + hexdecimal.Length];
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(array, 0, array.Length, bytes, 0);
Array.Copy(hexdecimal, 0, bytes, count, hexdecimal.Length);

// bytes contains all the bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function for converting `string to byte` and `byte to string`.

```
static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
  byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
  System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
  return bytes;
}

static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
{
  char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
  System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
  return new string(chars);
}
```

Comment: You obviously do not realize that `char` is a 16-bit value and this will fail miserably... Also, you need `unsafe`...